# file location which record error log in ionic serve

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

where is the file location which record log like this in ionic3?

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19461)
```

nb: this log is example when i do ionic serve

Comment: The very software you were using in order to retrieve the above output clearly logs it -- else you wouldn't have been able to see that output in the first place.

Comment: maybe i should change the question, what i mean is the location of the file. @ObsidianAge

Comment: I'm seeing the same error with the ionic version and line...